# Angular Project: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: angular

I'm almost resigning myself. I have this problem which I cannot solve. For my first project in angular, I ran into the following error:
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Array

Basically I created a service that calls an external json file
In the service I put these methods:

```
export class PiattiService {

  url="https://mywebsite.eccc/db.json";
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }




  get():Observable<Piatto[]>{
    return this.http.get<Piatto[]>(this.url);
  }
```

I created an interface class by declaring the fields equivalent to the json file I get

```
export class Piatto{
  id:number;
  titolo:string;
  image:string;
  label:string;
  prezzo:string;
  categoria:string;
  inevidenza:string;
  commenti:string;
}
```

In the COMPONENT TS file I call this service as follows:

```
export class MostrapiattiComponent implements OnInit {

  piatti:Piatto[];
 

  constructor(private http:HttpClient, private servizioPiatti:PiattiService) { }




  ngOnInit() {
      this.servizioPiatti.get().subscribe((osserva)=>{
      this.piatti=osserva;
    })
  }

}
```

In the html file I try and iterate everything from *ngfor

```
<tr *ngFor="let piatto of piatti ">
    <td>{{piatto.id}}</td><td>{{piatto.titolo}}</td>
  </tr>
```

But it goes wrong

Comment: Can you please include the content of the json file as well?

Comment: Is the `osserva` really type of `Piatto[]`. Seems like you're trying to assign different type of data to it

Comment: Json FILE is here: https://blog.keltawebagency.com/json-server/db.json

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `piatti:Piatto[]` with an empty array.

`piatti:Piatto[]=[];`

and you need to update the HTTP call as well because it is not returning array.

```js
return this.http.get<Piatto[]>(this.url).pipe(map(res=>res.piatti))
```

Comment: the error is the same:

Comment: RROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.js:21604)
    at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:3190)
    at callHook (core.js:2536)
    at callHooks (core.js:2495)
    at executeCheckHooks (core.js:2427)
    at refreshView (core.js:9481)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10643)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:9268)
    at refreshView (core.js:9522)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:10597)

Comment: can you please `console.log(osserva)` .

Comment: console.log(osserva) results:

{piatti: Array(4), insalate: Array(2), impasti: Array(2), chisiamo: Array(1), messaggi: Array(0), …}
chisiamo: [{…}]
impasti: (2) [{…}, {…}]
insalate: (2) [{…}, {…}]
messaggi: []
piatti: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
preferiti: []
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: `return this.http.get<Piatto[]>(this.url).map(res=>res.piatti)` try this whil doing http call

Comment: .map not is property for observable function. My get function is in service file.

export class PiattiService {

  url="urlforfilejson/db.json";
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }


  get():Observable<Piatto[]>{
    return this.http.get<Piatto[]>(this.url);
  }

Comment: `this.piatti=osserva.piatti;` do this in component file

Comment: TS2339: Property 'piatti' does not exist on type 'Piatto[]'.

Comment: I have solved. Problem is in array. I modify this in my component:
ngOnInit() {
      this.servizioPiatti.get().subscribe((osserva)=>{
      this.piatti=osserva['piatti'];
console.log(osserva)    })

  }

Comment: Yes, the problem was with the array but this is not the correct way, the correct way is to map the response while having an HTTP call, 
did you try with the updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

I Have Solved. Thank you for all

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).